# Destroy type in Julia

Tags: julia, free-variable

I have to destroy some type in Julia which looks like:

```
struct City
    x::Int
    y::Int
    index::Int
end
```

and I want a function like

```
  destroy(City)
```

that will delete this. Is it possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean by delete it?

Comment: @MattB. I mean free the memory. It should work like free() in C .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia is a [garbage collected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) language – you do not need to explicitly free the memory used by objects and there is no mechanism to do so. Garbage collection happens automatically in response to memory pressure, or you can invoke it manually be calling the `gc()` function.

Comment: What if I need to? Or how to tigger garbage collector?

Comment: Info added on how to call `gc()`. If you were to free a Julia object, your program would almost immediately crash.